# jQuery select box if option 1 is selected

Tags: jquery, selected, drop-down-menu, preventdefault

I have a problem writing a script that will prevent default behavior of submit button when option 1 from select box is selected. Here's the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/QgZHC/4/

Also on my website I'm using skinnable-select plugin but I don't know if that has any impact on the script. We'll be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:  http://jsfiddle.net/QgZHC/7/

Comment: also, I would use $('#dupa') to find the select by ID instead of by class or by element name.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go Below is the updated script of your fiddle :

```
$('.send').click(function(e) {
var a = $('.dupa').val();
if(a == "1")
{
     alert('Dupa');
     e.preventDefault();  
}
});
```

Also check this : http://jsfiddle.net/QgZHC/6/

Comment: I'd rather point to the select by ID than to all of the option elements of the page

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that is working because the alert doesn't display. Also when I select other options from select box value 1 still remains selected in html so the script will always prevent the default behavior of send button.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.send').click(function(e) {
    if ($('.dupa').val() == '2') {
       alert('Dupa');
       e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($('.dupa').attr('value') != 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.send').click(function(e) {
    if ($('.dupa option:selected').val()==1) {
       alert('Dupa');
       e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```